# run nutch1.9 in eclipse got error CrawlDb update: java.io.IOException: Job failed

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, nutch

I'm trying to run nutch 1.9 in eclipse, all of my config is according to this article(http://yewintko.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/setting-up-nutch-in-eclipse-indigo/). But I got this error :

```
CrawlDb update: starting at 2014-11-10 15:50:10
CrawlDb update: db: urls
CrawlDb update: segments: [3, crawl]
CrawlDb update: additions allowed: true
CrawlDb update: URL normalizing: false
CrawlDb update: URL filtering: false
CrawlDb update: 404 purging: false
CrawlDb update: Merging segment data into db.
CrawlDb update: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1357)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.CrawlDb.update(CrawlDb.java:119)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.CrawlDb.run(CrawlDb.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.CrawlDb.main(CrawlDb.java:179)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried following the steps from the [Nutch WIKI](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/RunNutchInEclipse) instead?